# Vaadin CDI - Injecting UI components

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, vaadin7

I'm evaluating Vaadin as an alternative presentation framework to JSF2. There seems to be a lot to like (especially as I'm no HTML/CSS wiz) but I'm getting a little confused regarding the correct way to utilise CDI as there is less of an obvious distinction between view and program logic (ironically enough, the dark side of the reason I like this framework!).

Obviously, business logic (EJBs, etc) should be injected using @Inject, but what about UI classes? As there doesn't seem any real point to avoiding tight coupling, I suspect that making certain objects such as the UI root layout and Vaadin servlet instance available via injection rather than the standard accessor methods would be good practice but individual Button or Label instances can be instantiated as normal.

Guidance from any CDI gurus much appreciated!

Comment: Thats what I do, to ... Inject and Produces for "high Level components" (UI, View, Controller, ...) but simple "new" for "simple components"

Comment: This is an interesting question I have thought about... I'm rather new to booth Vaadin 7 and EJB3 and CDI so I have struggled a bit with where to use what.

Comment: Missed the 5 min edit, continue... My approach have been to use CDI in components as much as possible (to be able to use CDI in the child components) and make use of of a init() method where I initiate things.. But I'm not really satisfied with that. For example where I want to reuse several of the same component in an panel depending on something it doesn't really work out for me.